# How do I wrap Debugger.Break nicely?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

`Debug.Assert` shows a confusing message box, but I want it to just break if `condition` is `false`.

The following works, but is tedious to write:

```
#if DEBUG
    if (!condition) Debugger.Break()
#endif
```

So I wrote the following function:

```
public class Util
{
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void Assert(bool condition)
    {
        if (!condition) Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

It works, but it breaks in the function and not at its call site. How do I make my `Assert` function behave like the `Break` function it wraps?

Comment: You could try to mark the method with the `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Matze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646942/matze)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191239/how-do-i-wrap-debugger-break-nicely/27191375#comment42868520_27191239) is correct. Decorating your `Assert` method with the [`DebuggerStepThrough`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute sets the break point on the call of the `Assert` method.

Test program:

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static void Assert(bool condition)
{
    if (!condition) Debugger.Break();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assert(false); // <-- break point here

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note that you have to turn `Just my code` on. Go to `Options -> Debugging -> Enable Just My Code`.

Comment: Maybe *Options->Debugging->Enable Just My Code* needs to be turned on.

Comment: @Ripple: That might be it! I have it turned on.

Comment: That did the trick. Add that to your answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

The `DebuggerStepThrough` attribute as mentioned in Patrick Hofman's answer did not work in my case. I am using Visual Studio 2022, maybe they changed how the debugger handles those attributes.

I had to use the `DebuggerHidden` attribute. It works with and without enabling `Just my code`.